# How can a non-geek set up a proper firewall?

Tags: firewall

Maybe a non-geek that knows of the existence of a firewall is already some kind of a nerd. If you have been a windows-user then it was rather easy to set up a firewall (I don't know if it was a good one!): enable a firewall with maximum protection. Then for each program that tried to make an internet-connection a notification was shown (allow or not allow). In this way without any prior knowledge of protocols and ports a user could set up a firewall that was suited to his needs. Is there any equivalent program in Ubuntu so that any user can set up a proper firewall?

Comment: For most people those questions are quite useless, as they don't know what to answer to them (e.g. they don't know how to find out if an application is really what it pretends to be).

Answer (score 7):

### gufw

gufw is an easy and intuitive way to manage your Linux firewall. It supports common tasks such as allowing or blocking preconfigured, common p2p, or individual port(s), and many others. To install gufw in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gufw
```

[image: gufw]

Comment: How can I see a list of the programs I use for accessing the internet? (Firefox, Thunderbird, VLC-player, ... ?)

Answer (score 2):

### Firestarter

```
sudo apt-get install firestarter
```

[image: Firestarter]

Comment: I know the program Firestarter (A little bit outdated, but it works fine). I don't believe that a non-geek can work with it! (I use wireshark to see how the communication works (protocol, port) and the set up my rules. I referred to the windows-firewall. Here a user receives a notification that an application, eg. Firefox will access the internet: allow or not allow? The user is only aware of the application (which (s)he most likely is aware of) and not of the communication involved. In this way one can set up a firewall without any specific communications-knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a router, and you have not disabled it then you most likely are behind a what they refer to as a "hardware firewall", for most users this is fine...