# Is there any Application level firewall for Ubuntu 16.04? (with GUI)

Tags: software-recommendation, firewall

I must confess that I'm very new to Linux world, and there are concepts that seem very unfamiliar to me.

One thing I miss the most is a good yet simple application level firewall. As of now, with all this pervasive intrusive and permanent connectivity to the internet it is a must to know what exactly is your computer doing, why and with whom. A protocol analyzer is ok but too unfriendly and time consuming to "analyze" that is practically useless for home users.

I have discovered a lot of programs in Windows environments that should not connect to the internet but they do (and with my ZoneAlarm free firewall I can stop them).

With Gufw (and several others) you have to know which apps do you have already installed (and we know that this is almost impossible with this modern OS´s with billions of code-lines).

What I'm looking for is a firewall that monitors the NIC/WAN connection and detects any program/app or whatever trying to "talk" through it proactively, regardless the port trying to use (must of the apps I mentioned earlier try to connect using well know TCP ports: 80, 443, 8080). Does this exist? (If not, then how I know what is doing my computer for sure?)

Comment: Just curious: Has this snake oil prevented any serious problems (like wannacry) lately?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can a non-geek set up a proper firewall?](https://askubuntu.com/q/7757/125475)

Answer (score 11):

[Douane](http://douaneapp.com/)

> Douane is a personal firewall that protects a user's privacy by allowing a user to control which applications can connect to the internet from their GNU/Linux computer.

---

## Installation

Until now (2017/05/22) there isn't Ubuntu packages available. You must build it from source.

These installation instructions are based on information from the [Douane Wiki](https://github.com/Douane/Douane/wiki) and tested on Ubuntu 16.04.2 64-bit.

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to run the commands.

### Preparation

Update your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```

If you get a notification asking to restart your computer, then restart it.

### Install the dependencies

```
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms libboost-filesystem-dev libboost-regex-dev libboost-signals-dev policykit-1 libdbus-c++-dev libdbus-1-dev liblog4cxx10-dev libssl-dev libgtkmm-3.0-dev python3 python3-gi python3-dbus
```

### Create a directory for compilation

```
cd
mkdir Douane
cd Douane
```

### Build the kernel module

```
git clone https://github.com/Douane/douane-dkms
cd douane-dkms
sudo make dkms
```

Check if the module was built and installed correctly:

```
lsmod | grep douane
```

You should see something like:

```
douane                 20480  0
```

### Build the daemon

```
cd ~/Douane
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Douane/douane-daemon
cd douane-daemon
make
sudo make install
```

### Build the dialog process

```
cd ~/Douane
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Douane/douane-dialog
cd douane-dialog
make
sudo make install
```

Start the dialog process:

```
/opt/douane/bin/douane-dialog &
```

Then check if it is running:

```
pgrep -a douane-dialog
```

You should see something like:

```
21621 /opt/douane/bin/douane-dialog
```

### Build the configurator

```
cd ~/Douane
git clone https://github.com/Douane/douane-configurator
cd douane-configurator
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

### Start the daemon and setup automatic starting

I had to insert the following text in the file `/etc/init.d/douane` in order to enable the automatic starting of the daemon:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          douane
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Douane firewall
### END INIT INFO
```

Open the file for edit:

```
sudo nano /etc/init.d/douane
```

Then paste the above text after the program description. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>,<kbd>Enter</kbd> to save, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the editor.

This is the first 21 lines of the file after I inserted the text:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# douane      This shell script takes care of starting and stopping
#             douane daemon (A modern firewall at application layer)
#
# Author: Guillaume Hain zedtux@zedroot.org
#
# description: douane is the daemon process of the Douane firewall application. \
# This firewall is limiting access to the internet on application bases.

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          douane
# Required-Start:
# Required-Stop:
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Douane firewall
### END INIT INFO

# Source function library.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

Now you can set up the auto start and start the daemon:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable douane
sudo systemctl start douane
```

### Activate the filter and auto start the dialog

Start the configurator:

```
douane-configurator
```

Then make sure the switches **Use Douane to filter my network traffic** and **Auto start Douane on boot** are both turned on.

You can review the filtering rules in the **Rules** tab. Right clicking a rule you get an option to delete it.

### Test

If everything is fine you should see the Douane window asking for permission when you open applications that uses network connections.

Comment: Hi Eric, thank you very much for your promptly answer. As mentioned I'm quite novice with Linux. I did found this Douane thing before post my question, I took a look on the Douane site and there is no "package" for Ubuntu, only for something called "Archlinux" (I guess another distro of linux)... I also found that one can adapt this to whatever distro making a recompilation and installation manually... am I right?... nobody has this already compiled and packaged for ubuntu?

Comment: First of all thank you again Eric for the support..Uhm... more than 30 steps to put up and running an app in linux... not very user friendly, isn't it?... I´m starting to see why Linux has that very low reception outside techie people... I will give it a try (mainly because I have to break apart from M$ Windoze at any cost)

Comment: Isn’t there a [PPA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them) to provide binaries? Google found https://launchpad.net/~zedtux/+archive/ubuntu/douane (but I haven’t tested it).

Answer (score 4):

There is a new project called OpenSnitch described at

https://www.cyberciti.biz/python-tutorials/opensnitch-the-little-snitch-application-like-firewall-tool-for-linux/

The project page is https://www.opensnitch.io/

At this point it is considered alpha software, and strangely it is written in Python, but at least it is a fresh attempt, whereas Douane is a very old program that (I think) is much harder to install.

Disclaimer:  I have not personally tested either program, I was just trying to find if there are any other options and noticed that no one had mentioned OpenSnitch here yet.

Comment: > "strangely it is written in Python" — no it's not strangely, it's actually a very good idea to use a high level language for everything except the "hot" parts to save time and to make less mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a really good question, but I hate questions like this because they are really hard to answer without coming off like saying security is not important.

So first, let me say that security is important, but that Linux handles it very differently then Windows does.

So lets tackle your question.

First there is not going to be a outgoing firewall that works in the same way as zone alarm. Linux simply doesn't have a large need for one. Many applications work in a client/server architecture even though you are using them on the same machine. Xorg is a great example. First you have a server (in this case the part that draws on the screen) and a client (gedit) gedit talks to the server about drawing it's buttons, placing it's text and so on. Even something as simple os a mouse has this same architecture (or could have). A program acts as a server listening for information and sending out data when it gets it, then a client "connects" to that "mouse server"  and waits for information.

This is so prevalent in Linux that if you were to create a "firewall" that asked permission for every network connection then you probably wouldn't be able to configure it because it couldn't connect to it's own server.

This is all a very rough example, some of it is misleading because it is so high level. But it's still very true.

To protect us Linux users against this, we have a set of two very basic rules that do a very good "basic" job.

1st, no user except root can open any port below 1024. (again very high level). This means to even run an FTP server (on a standard port) you need to have root access. You as a user can usually open "high ports" (those above 1024). But see rule two.

2nd. no process can access any file that the user starting the process could not access. (again very high level) So if "coteyr" were to start an FTP server, then that FTP server at worse case (high level) would only have the exact same access as the user coteyr that started it.

Because of the combination of these two rules, a "software" that asks every time something tries to connect firewall just gets in the way, and there isn't a lot of demand for it.

That said you can always create an outbound firewall rule, and in many cases this is probably not a bad idea. Many services can be (and are by default) configured to use file based sockets (or memory based) and not network based sockets.

An Inbound firewall rule usually closes any odd gapes left over by rule 1 or 2.

My point is this. Security is important and I am not trying to say it's not, it's just here in Linux land we have different tools and goals. I would recommend that you look into Linux user and group permissions and then use a tool like gfw and IPTABLES to fill in any gaps.

Comment: *> no process can access any file that the user starting the process could not access* — which is no different from Windows, as you seem to be implying. That's not an OS difference. Honestly, though, if you just allowed all loopback connections then such a firewall would not interfere with any TCP client/server applications on the same machine — it's perfectly possible to set one up that only controls network access. (Also. Unless you're running Windows 9x, Windows ACLs are, if anything, more powerful than traditional Unix permissions. Which again has little to do with restricting network.)

Comment: Actually, reading the answer again... I'm not sure how not being able to use well-known ports is relevant either - that's only useful to prevent masking of system services (e.g. pretending to be `sshd` on 22), but the question seems to be asking more about data exfiltration. Which are almost entirely outgoing connections and have little to do with which ports you're allowed to bind to.

Comment: First there is not going to be a outgoing firewall that works in the same way as zone alarm. Linux simply doesn't have a large need for one - IP tables will control outgoing just as well as in coming, please don't say stuff you don't actually know.

Comment: Hi Honza, during my "homework" tour I saw several times answers like yours. And I somewhat understand it, but... and is a big "but"... is not what I'm looking for... I do understand the port, low exposure (due to the low widespread of the platform) and all the other concepts you mentioned... but what I´m looking for is to understand in a easy way (e.g. zonealarm) what is my computer doing outside the computer itself.. (is Xorg/gedit, to follow your example, in need to go to internet to do anything? if so I want/need to know why/when/where...

Comment: Then your going to dig a bit deeper. try `netstat` Right now my box has 1354 open connections. 65 of those are network connections. That's quite a low number for me (not saying it is for everyone) but then you would start trying to find out what each one of those connections does. Like I said, it's not that security is not important, it's just a very different environment.

Answer (score 1):

OpenSnitch, which was mentioned in an answer here, [is no longer under active development](https://github.com/evilsocket/opensnitch/issues/259#issuecomment-498604956). There's [a fork](https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch) though that continues the development, which has improved in many areas over the now unmaintained OpenSnitch.

Like the original project, the OpenSnitch fork is a free an open source application-level firewall for Linux that's made of a daemon (written in Go) and a GUI (PyQt5). Also like the original project, this fork is work in progress, with a message on its project page saying to "do not expect it to be bug free and do not rely on it for any type of security".

The application monitors outbound connections that your applications are trying to make, preventing or permitting their connection based on a set of rules (the user is prompted to allow or deny access when no existing rules are found). The application is inspired by Little Snitch, a commercial host-based application firewall for macOS.

For Ubuntu there are DEB packages available for download on the project [GitHub](https://github.com/gustavo-iniguez-goya/opensnitch/releases).

[Source](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/03/opensnitch-linux-application-firewall.html).