# Can a firewall filter ip addresses?

Tags: security, firewall, ip

The Linux firewall can filter ports but can it also block ip addresses from securing a connection?

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu uses ufw firewall, check here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a non-geek set up a proper firewall?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7757/how-can-a-non-geek-set-up-a-proper-firewall)